# Unhide a hidden community

Tags: support, user-accounts, hidden-communities

I have 3 hidden communities and would like to un-hide one of them. I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this. How do I unhide the hidden community?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to [Profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current) -> [Edit Profile & Settings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current) -> [Hide Communities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/hidecommunities/current)

In the bottom, you can see the hidden communities.

Click on the Unhide button:

> [image]

Comment: Finally an answer to this that also has links! Way to go